# How to mock node modules from subdirectories in the root directory of a monorepo?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, monorepo

I am using jest with typescript, and currently have a monorepo with a structure like this:

```
root
|-service1
|--.jest.config.ts
|--package.json
|--tsconfig.json
|-service2
|--.jest.config.ts
|--package.json
|--tsconfig.json
|-package.json
|-.jest.config.ts
```

Where each of the `service1` and `service2` projects, are their own project with a `src` folder, and `node_modules` etc...

Now what I want to do, is create some test files in the root of the project, that encompass all of the functions in the `service1` and `service2` projects. Some of these functions use node modules such as `axios` and `@aws-sdk`, which I want to mock.

The issue I seem to be facing, is that when i write a test file like this in the root: (`root/e2e.test.ts`)

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { someFuncThatCallsAxios } from './service1/src/someFile'

describe('E2E tests', () => {
  it('...', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(axios, 'request').mockResolvedValue('Success')

    await someFuncThatCallsAxios()
  })
})
```

Axios is not getting mocked... I can only assume this has something to do with the fact that it is picking up `axios` from the root's `node_modules`, and when the function from `service1` is called, it is referencing the `axios` from that project's `node_modules` .

Is there some way that I can successfully mock the dependencies from the subdirectory projects in this monorepo?

I tried doing something along the lines of:
`import axios from './service1/node_modules/axios`
but then I just got a bunch of jest errors that upon trying to resolve, ultimately proving that wasn't the solution..

I am trying to create a set of E2E tests that will cover the functionality from all the projects in a single run, rather than individual unit tests for each service, and with my project structure I just can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated!